When is it appropriate to ask a question at two different SE sites?
I once was told that asking a mathematical question simultaneously at MathOverflow and Mathematics SE was bad practice. It was recommended to first ask it at one of both sites. If the question was more advanced: first at MO, if more basic: first at MSE. Only after a couple of days without an answer, ask it at the other site.
I'm facing the same situation with respect to Biology SE and Cognitive Sciences SE. In this case, the distinction is not between more or less advanced, but between two different approaches to the same question/problem concerning (cognitive) neurosciences.
Is it OK to ask the same question simultaneously at BSE and CGSE, e.g. this one: Criticism of the significance of fMRI studies?

If you ask the same question differently (with a different focus), so that both sites would attract different types of answers, I see no problem in double-posting. In essence, it is no longer the same question on both sites ...

I just read the question you linked to and in case you would want to double-post this question you would have to tailor it to each site more specifically. E.g. on Biology you could ask about the underlying biology of what fMRI in fact measures, and on CogSci you could ask in more detail about what can be inferred from that. Whether you want to narrow it down like this or not depends on your initial knowledge and what you are after exactly. However, do not just double-post the exact same question!

Interesting to ask an exact dupe meta post over at Bio :-) Well, see my comment there...

@AliceD since an answer is missing here, could you perhaps share a link to the bio meta-post?
